# After deleting and rebuilding tenants with the same name, the old user still exists in cnosdb

Tags: cnosdb

To Reproduce:

Run cnosdb in singleton mode, then start cnosdb-cli run below commands:

```
create tenant if not exists tenant1;
create user if not exists user1;
alter tenant tenant1 add user user1 as owner;
drop tenant if exists tenant1;
create tenant if not exists tenant1;
```

Then execute `alter tenant tenant1 add user user1 as owner;`

Show error:

```
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"030007","error_message":"The user 19812744502392072301122323264259877424 already exists"}
```